# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column of relation does not exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, beautifulsoup

Trying to insert data into PostgreSQL database.

Python code:

```
myFields = ((DOT_Number,),(Entity_Type,),(Operating_Status,),(Legal_Name,),
(Phone,),(Address,)
)

query = """ INSERT INTO saferdb_question( DOT_Number, Entity_Type, Operating_Status, Legal_Name, Phone, Address)VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""

cur.execute( query, myFields)
```

Getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 189, in <module>
    cur.execute( query, myFields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 144, in execute
    return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "dot_number" of relation "saferdb_question" does not exist
LINE 1:  INSERT INTO saferdb_question( DOT_Number, Entity_Type, Oper...
```

SQL from PostgreSQL that created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.saferdb_question
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('saferdb_question_id_seq'::regclass),
    "DOT_Number" character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
```

...

```
    "Phone" character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Address" character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,

)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.saferdb_question
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: error says `column "dot_number" of relation "saferdb_question" does not exist`  - are you sure you have column `"dot_number"` in table `"saferdb_question"` in your database ?

Comment: @furas I just added the sql from postgresql that created the table. The "dot_number" looks like it was created.

Comment: if you have this table then: are you sure you connected with correct database ?

Comment: @furas  I only have one database.

Comment: Maybe you have one database but you connected with different computer, not your database. Other idea: use your `INSERT` query directly in database (using `pgadmin` or similar tool) - maybe it gives you more useful informations.

Comment: @furas tried the command in postgrsql got the same error... This data base was created using Django do you think that is part of the problem?

Comment: now your problem is database, not code in question. Do you have problems when you use this database in Django ?

Comment: I can insert data using the django shell.

Comment: You have `"DOT_Number"` column but trying to insert `"dot_number"` column. There are a lot info here about case sensitivity of the quoted identifiers. In few words: if you create quoted identifiers then you **always** should to use quoted identifiers in same case.

Comment: @Adelisto I tried the query lower case: "INSERT INTO saferdb_question( dot_number) VALUES('1234')"

Comment: Your query should be `INSERT INTO saferdb_question( "DOT_Number") VALUES('1234')` Here column name should be exactly same as in the `create table` statement. PS: Do not use double quotes in DDL statement to avoid such problems.

Comment: @Abelisto I tried your suggestion: query = """INSERT INTO saferdb_question( "dot_number") VALUES("1234")""" no luck

Comment: It is not my suggestion. My suggestion was `query = """INSERT INTO saferdb_question( "DOT_Number") VALUES('1234')"""` Please be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved this.
The columns had to be in quotes. Here is the final Query string:

```
query = """ INSERT INTO public.saferdb_question( "DOT_Number", "Entity_Type", "Operating_Status", "Legal_Name", "Phone", "Address")VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""
```